# remove 'Processing' instead of hide

Tags: datatables

When we start sorting or other things datatables has option to show 'Process' message. All is fine , only when it hides 'Processing' there is still stay space where 'Processing' is placed. So html table jumping down when Processing showing then when data have been loaded Processing hidding but html table isn't jumping back up so there is stay visible place for it.
Question, how to make datatable to remove Processing tag instead of just hide. Thanks

EDIT. I add html code

```
<div id="search_table_processing" class="dataTables_processing" style="visibility: hidden;">Processing...<img alt="&lt; &lt;" src="/themes/third_party/linkedin_search/img/165.gif"></div>
```

Comment: Is this spam? Otherwise I think that at least a code example is required, ot more context, to answer this question.

Comment: if you know what datatables is you will know what i am talking about

Comment: This is not the default behavior of datatables... post your code snippet

Comment: are you talking about http://datatables.net/ ? if so , all you want is a custom processing text/image? , cause i'm no familiar with your suggested solution , instead i can show you another one...

Comment: yes, about datatables.net, what solution do you mean? I have q question not solution

Comment: in case you were looking for a proper way to set a custom image while datatbles process data i posted a solution....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well drat, I just ran into this and had to dig into it myself.

In version 1.9.0 you can search for this snippet:

```
an[i].style.visibility = bShow ? "visible" : "hidden";
```

(Found after searching for `visibility`.)

In the minified version it's currently this (using the NuGet package):

```
c[d].style.visibility=b?"visible":"hidden";
```

The problem is we neglected to style `.dataTables_processing`, as per the sample CSS files. Here's what one of the samples has for styling:

```
.dataTables_processing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 2px 0;
}
```

Once it's styled (or `bProcessing` is set to false), there shouldn't be an issue.

If you're comfortable changing the functionality of the plug-in (if you think you can remember to change it back), then you could switch it to use display instead of visibility.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using Internationalisation - "oLanguage" attribute in your datatables constructor

replace the old sProcessing value with this in your localization file in order to place a custom image while processing :

```
"sProcessing":   "<img src='/themes/third_party/linkedin_search/img/165.gif'/>",
```

and here is how you link your datatables to a localization file (which can be downloaded from the datatables website [Internationalisation of datatables](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n))
.
.
.

```
        "oLanguage": {
           "sUrl": "../../jQuery/dataTables/media/MyLanguageFilesFolder/en_US.txt"
         }
```

.
.
.

If you not using the Internationalisation of datatables you can always set the "sProcessing" value with the suggested above...

here an example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "<img src='/themes/third_party/linkedin_search/img/165.gif'>"
    }
} );
```

} );

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
    an[i].style.visibility = bShow ? "visible" : "hidden";
```

to

```
    an[i].style.display = bShow ? "block" : "none";
```

didn't work for me. However, I accomplished it by changing the statement to

```
    if (bShow == false) {
          an[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
       an[i].style.display = "block";
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone who doesn't want to add any css code and just go right to the source!

Answer (score 1):

For the Datatables version 1.9.4, just edit the file jquery.dataTables.js line 3005, and change the following:

```
an[i].style.visibility = bShow ? "visible" : "hidden";"block" : "none";
```

to

```
an[i].style.display = bShow ?
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to go away while the backdrop should be there, why not just add:

div.dataTables_processing{ color: transparent; }